# Check if a dataframe column contains decimal values

Tags: r

Sample Dataframe

`df<- data.frame(column1=c("row1", "row2", "row3", "row4", "row5", "row6"), column2=c(1,3,4.3,5,6.5,7.8))`

check if `df$column2` contains decimals. The result should be a `TRUE` or `FALSE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```r
round(df$column2) != df$column2
```

Since you cannot create a column of internals and doubles, we improperly assume that if the decimal part is 0, then the number is integer.

If you are interested in knowing if the column contains at least one decimal use

```r
any(round(df$column2) != df$column2)
```

If you are interested in knowing if all the column values ​​are decimal use

```r
all(round(df$column2) != df$column2)
```

Comment: Thanks @Leonardo. the solution `any(round(df$column2) != df$column2)` works for me

Comment: Very good! If it was useful to you, if you want, accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use the modulus operator.

x%%1==0 will check if the modulus (x mod 1) is 0

x%%1!=0 will check if the modulus (x mod 1) is not 0, which means its value has decimals

This will give you elementwise results:

```
> df$column2%%1!=0
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

for an aggregate on the whole column, call

```
any(df$column2%%1!=0)

[1] TRUE
```